# DevExpress' ASPxCombobox

Tags: devexpress

How to retrieve the first value displayed on the DevExpress' ASPxCombobox connecting to a SQL data source?  After the page first loads, if I use selectedItem to retrieve the first value displayed on the ASPxCombo box without clicking on the combobox, I will get "null" for selectedItem.  When I click and choose a value from a combobox, I can use selectedItem to get that value.

Comment: On page load, are you trying to select the ASPxCombobox value from the client side or the server side?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, JAKEtheJAB.  I was trying to select the ASPxCombobox value from the server side.  An example is, the combobox is in the editItemTemplate of gridview; its data for an specific row retrieved from the gridview's datasource, and connected with another sqldatasource for the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

To access elements in dropdown window of ASPxComboBox use its Items collection:

```html
//retrieve value of the first element in dropdown window of ASPxComboBox 

var firstItem = comboBox.Items[0].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Combobox selecteditem would not be available on Page Load. Data isn't bound to control at this point, instead use DataBound event.

Webform1.aspx

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" TextField="CategoryName" ValueField="CategoryID">
</dx:ASPxComboBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NWindConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categories]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Webform1.aspx.cs

```
void ASPxComboBox1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ASPxComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
   object selectedItem = ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem;
   string selectedValue = ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your Page_Load:

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
    cmb.DataBind();
    cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first item in the combobox then use:

```
ASPxComboBox1.Items[0]
```

If you want to get the selected value then use:

```
ASPxComboBox1.Value
```